# findAndModify() giving exception in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a following code to update a document in a subcollection field, and I am getting the exception followed by the code.

```
router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/accept/').post(function(req, res) {
    Host.findAndModify({
        "query" : {
            "_id" : req.body.eventid,
            "joinees" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "userid" : req.body.userid
                }
            }
        },
        "update" : {
            "$set" : {
                "joinees.$.status_code" : 1
            },
        },
        "new" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    }, function(err, host) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            console.log("kanishka");
            res.json(host);

        }
    });
});
```

Exception printed in console is given below:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.handle (/node/Playo1/server1.js:332:7)
    at next_layer (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24
    at param (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:268:14)
    at param (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:16)
    at param (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:16)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
    at next (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/node/Playo1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
```

Comment: `.findAndModify()` is not a method of mongoose models. See [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) or [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) which are special purpose wrappers to the underlying driver method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. This will work.

```
router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/accept/')
.post(function(req, res) {

        Host.findOneAndUpdate({
                "_id" : req.body.eventid,
                "joinees" : {
                        "$elemMatch" : {
                                "userid" : req.body.userid
                        }
                }
        }, {
                "$set" : {
                        "joinees.$.status_code" : 1
                }
        }, {
                "new" : true,
                "upsert" : false
        }, function(err, host) {
                if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.json(err);
                } else {
                        res.json({
                                message : "request Accepted",
                                requestStatus : 1
                        });
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: I am trying this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: not working for me, same error `TypeError: Collections.findOneAndUpdate is not a function`